# how to install python library (Imported in our script file) automatically in windows 7

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script file named `updatesCode.py`

inside this file i am importing `openpyxl`,

i downloaded the tar file and extracted , went to setup.py file directory and ran `python setup.py install`  because pip was not working in my case.

my question is : if i give my `updatedCode.py` to some one else, it will give error related to installation of the `opepyxl` library

Is there any way(like a script file that installs library) to insatll openpyxl library automatically before running `updatedCode.py.`

i tried to write a setup.py file but it didnt work. please give me suggestions to achieve this (how to specify dependencies in `setup.py` file )

`updatedCode.py` file has simple code to access a excel sheet, I am not creating a package.